# Disable "Reply" and/or "Reply to all" (PHP)

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer, reply

I have an email address only for sending mails.
Can I send messages with disabled "Reply" and/or "Reply to all" properties using SwiftMailer (I can work with another library too)?

Thanks in advance...

```
<?php
$mail = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject('My Subject')
        ->setFrom('noreply@domain.abc', 'NoReply')
        ->setTo('to@domain.abc')
        ->setBody('<b>My Text</b>', 'text/html');
```

*P.S. Most of the recipients use Outlook but some of them use Thunderbird.*

Comment: What does it do if you add `->setReplyTo(null)` ?

Comment: Whatever you do manage to do with this will just be a suggestion to the recipient and cannot actually force the recipient to do or not do anything.

Comment: These are not properties of the message but options of the mail client that the receiver is using. So no, you cannot do that.

Comment: I thought this might be worth asking... Unfortunately `->setReplyTo(null)` does not help. Thank you all!